confuse about Qur'anic verse 2 of surah hud
The Quran is regarded as the word and speech of Allah. However, there is a query regarding verse 11.2, which states

"I am a warner from Him,"

suggesting that Prophet Muhammad (SAW) is the warner or prophet from Allah. This phrase could imply that it is a direct speech from Prophet Muhammad (SAW) because it does not frame the statement as a command or message conveyed by the prophet to the people. Thus, when taken literally, the verse appears to be spoken by the Prophet himself, even though the Quran is the word of Allah.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. As to your question, where is the problem? The whole context actually shows that Muhammad is the warner from Allah and what you regard as problematic might be regarded as more eloquent in Arabic language.
